# How to print a list of strings to a file in a table format?

Tags: c, formatting

i have an array in a fixed size:
    `library[BOOKNUM]`

each item in the array is a `struct book`.

**Struct Book**

```
typedef struct _book{

    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char authors[AUTHORS_NAME_LENGTH];
    char publisher[PUBLISHER_NAME_LENGTH];
    char genre[GENRE_LENGTH];
    int year;
    int num_pages;
    int copies;
}book;
```

My goal is to print a list of files like this:

```
Name                    Author                Publisher                     Genre ...
War and Remembrance     Herman Wouk           Good Books Publishing, LtD    Historic Novel 
Zzz, from A to Z        Noam Chomsky          Bad Books Publishing, LtD     Linguistics
Splitting the Atom      Margaret Openheimer   Science Books Publishing, inc Nuclear Physics
```

and so on for all the books and all the attributes.

I tried putting `\t` between attribute, didn't work.

I tried printing between each attribute (30-len(attribute))* spaces, didn't work.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You should show what you've tried.  Read the specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) again (I'm assuming you've read it once already).  It is easy enough to specify field widths and left alignment; you can even truncate overlong strings if you need to.

Comment: SO is not a code writing website. Also don't ask answers for you're homework.

Comment: @AshishAhuja Please don't italicize _the_ when editing posts. It almost never makes grammatical sense. Also, `code` highlights are for actual language keywords, constants, names, etc. "attribute" is neither a C keyword nor a name in the above code, formatting it as `attribute` is confusing and harms readability.

Comment: @PaulRoub, thanks for letting me know. I'll change it right now. I won't do the same mistake again.

Comment: Please check @Rabbid76's answer or mine. They do work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

`printf( "%-30s", str );` prints `str` and fills the string with blanks at the end, up to `30` characters. `printf( "%-*s", len, str );` prints `str` and fills the string with blanks at the end, up to `len` characters.

Here is a function which prints the strings of `struct book`. Each column gets  a fixed length:

```
print_book( book *b )
{
    printf( "%-*s", NAME_LENGTH, book->name);
    printf( "%-*s", AUTHORS_NAME_LENGTH, book->authors);
    printf( "%-*s", PUBLISHER_NAME_LENGTH, book->publisher);
    printf( "%-*s", GENRE_LENGTH, book->genre);
}
```

Similar function printing to file:

```
fprint_book( FILE *f, book *b )
{
    fprintf( f, "%-*s", NAME_LENGTH, book->name);
    fprintf( f, "%-*s", AUTHORS_NAME_LENGTH, book->authors);
    fprintf( f, "%-*s", PUBLISHER_NAME_LENGTH, book->publisher);
    fprintf( f, "%-*s", GENRE_LENGTH, book->genre);
}
```

Comment: Might as well use OP's  `NAME_LENGTH` for `namelen`, etc.

Comment: The `+1` not really needed as `char name[NAME_LENGTH]` will have, at most, `NAME_LENGTH-1` characters to print and using `"%-*s", NAME_LENGTH, book->name);` will insure a leading space.  But this is a minor point and is the right approach to solving OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum length (and it seems so) of each column, you can just check how long is the value you are printing (for example if the `NAME` is 25 characters and the maximum length of the column is 30), you can fill the remaining 5 unused characters with spaces, so you don't have to worry about indentation.

However, `printf()` has very useful ways to define the maximum width.
For example, the

```
printf("%-15s\n", "Hello, world!");
```

statement prints the string, but prints 15 characters. If the string is smaller, the “empty” positions will be filled with “whitespaces”.

Check [here](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) for some useful examples.

Comment: i'm using     fprintf() for printing into a file. does it works the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can format a string to specify the length when you use `printf`.

For example:

```
//prints out a c string that takes up 20 spaces
printf("%20s", str);            

// printing multiple c strings
printf("%20s%25s", str1, str2);
```

Make sure you specify a number of spaces (in the first case, 20) for your string to take up that you will never exceed.